# different drawable resolutions

Tags: android

I want to deploy my application on different screen sizes using the 1.6 feature.
I exported the drawable resources with different resolutions in drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-hdpi folders.
On android 1.6 and 2.0 everything looks good.

My problem is that on 1.5 the drawable-ldpi resources are used instead of drawable or drawable-mdpi ... the application still works but it renders the images scaled and the image quality is lost.

How can I configure the application so that on 1.5 the only the drawable-mdi folder will be used?

I'd like to keep the apilevel to 3 so that the same apk will run on 1.5, 1.6 and 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `-v4` to your `-ldpi`, `-mdpi`, and `-hdpi` directory names, and having a base `res/drawable/` for use by Android 1.5.

Comment: This fixed the resolution for 1.5 but now the 2.0 emulator shows scaled mdpi images instead of hdpi on a wvga854 setup... -v4 suffix seems to be a way to specify that these images are to be used where only api 4 is available.
Where did you read out about this suffix?

Comment: I forgot to mention that on 1.6 wvga it works fine... only 2.0 wvga has problems now

Comment: I found a fix ... it is enough to mark only the ldpi with v4 so that the application behaves well on all platforms.

Thanks