# Multiple Screen Support - Choosing only the file in drawable folder

Tags: android, android-resources, android-screen-support

I have three images *MyImage* in `drawable`, `drawable-mdpi` and `drawable-hdpi` folders. The contents of all three images are different.

My question is, Is there a way of programmatically ensuring that only the image from `drawable` is displayed even though the device I run the app on supports mdpi/hdpi resolutions ?

Also can this be done without having to remove the images in the `mdpi` or `hdpi` folders.

Comment: The image inside `drawable` will *never* display without changing your resource structure, as `drawable` is an alias to `drawable-mdpi` for [compatibility reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1661683/1204134).

Comment: You might wanna try with different file names?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use bellow code.

```
   DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

           ((Activity) mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getMetrics(metrics);

           int density = metrics.densityDpi;

    if (density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM) {


    } else if (density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH) {


    } else if (density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH) {


    } else if (density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV) {


    } else {


    }
```